# Recurrence Equations: Uneven amount of letters

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations, recursion

I have a recurrence relation problem that states the following:

Given the alphabet $\sum = \{a,b,c\}$ how many words can be formed that have an uneven amount of "a"'s

From my understanding:
Each time the length of the word is increased by one, the are $3^n$ more possible words:

$x_0 = \lambda$

$x_1 = a \lor b \lor c$

$x_2 = aa \lor ab \lor ac \lor ba \lor bb \lor bc \lor ca \lor cb \lor  cc$

And so on.

Besides, from the examples I gave I can see the following "pattern"

$x_0 = 0 $ (0 referring to the amount of words with uneven a's)

$x_1 = 1$ (a)

$x_2 = 4$ (ab,ac,ba,ca)

But even "knowing" all of this, I'm not able to deduce the answer.
According to my professor the recurrence relation is:
$x_{n+1} = 2x_n + (3^n - x_n)$; and the solution is $x_n = \frac{3^n -1}{2}$

Comment: An integer which is not even is said to be *odd*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uneven = Odd !

If there are $x_n$ words of length $n$ with an odd number of $a$'s then there are $3^n-x_n$ words of length $n$ with an even number of $a$'s.

To form words of length $n+1$ (with an odd number of $a$'s) we can EITHER add $b$ or $c$ to the $x_n$ OR we can add $a$ to the words with an even number of $a$'s.

So the recurruence for $x_{n+1}$ is ...

Comment: How can we symbolize the addition of either b or c??

Comment: Where I said "add" $b$ or $c$ I mean string concatenation/ put it on the end of the word ... to creat a word of length $1$ longer.